# Scope of powers for special counsel?

Tags: united-states

Citing "unusual circumstances", the deputy attorney general of the US has appointed a special counsel.  What are the tools available to this role and what limitations are in place regarding those tools?  For instance, my understanding is that the special counsel has wide-ranging power to issue subpoenas, but do those have to be approved by the justice department? I've also read that the special counsel can prosecute anyone who interferes in the investigation with which he's tasked, but how would that work in practice?

Comment: Start by reading [28 CFR Part 600](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/28/part-600).

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, Thanks, that's very helpful.  News reports don't say much beyond 'broad-ranging' powers and I'm very curious to better understand what's going on.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, it sounds like the special counsel doesn't get any special powers, per se, but rather is given special jurisdiction that allows exercising those powers more broadly?